# Autowired in JUnit: only binds fields in Test class, not in other classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, autowired

I have the following Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/**/context.xml")
public class HAD_Test extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private UgcService ugcService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // this binding works fine
        Ugc ugc = ugcService.getRegistro(138355);
        ...
        HAD_Data dData = new HAD_Data(ugc);
        data.init();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then I have this other class:

```
public class HAD_Data {
    @Autowired
    private ClimaService climaService;

    public void init() {
        ...
        // at this point, climaService is null
        climaService.getRegistro(556)
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that the bindings in the Test class are being applied perfectly, but in any class I use, like HAD_Data, where there exist other autowired fields, these ones are not binded. They always have a null value.

I don't really know why these bindings are not been assigned. Can anybody help me please? If any other information is necessary, I can include it, but I think that my context.xml is correct, cause there exist some bindings applied ok.

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect Spring to inject the field if you are the one creating the object?

```
HAD_Data dData = new HAD_Data(ugc);
```

Spring can only autowire managed beans.

Add a bean declaration in your `context.xml` for `HAD_Data` and use that. You can also use `@PostConstruct` on the `init()` method so that Spring takes care of calling it after initialization.

---

Also, note that Java conventions discourage the use of `_` in class names.

Comment: You're completely right. I was wront creating the objects by myself. I should use always the autowired when I have a property that I want to be filled automatically by Spring.

I also had another error, cause I really access to these autobinded fields in the constructor, and that's absolutelly wrong too.

Thanks